# Remove website pages from search results, but keep them crawled

Tags: robots.txt

I would like to remove all pages of my website from the search results, except the home page. Is there a way to do this and keep the pages crawlable? Or is there no way except robots.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do noindex/follow in this case.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
```

If the page is already indexed and you want to take it out, you can use your GWT account to manually remove it. Next time that page gets crawled it wont get picked up if you implement the tag above.